# help with /etc/os-release echo $VERSION_CODENAME'

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, bash

How can i make this :
bash -c '. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME'

so it look like this :
get_codename() {
local VERSION_CODENAME
VERSION_CODENAME=$(. /etc/os-release | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$VERSION_CODENAME"
}

so it work with :
VERSION_CODENAME=$(get_codename)

It will print lowercase letters, but it should print so the first letter is uppercase

Comment: Why should the first letter be upper case?

Comment: I don't see any `cat` in your script. Are you sure it does anything?

Comment: The uppercase is my folder like Buster and Bullseye.
/RPI-Backup/${VERSION_CODENAME/${HOSTNAME}/"
but is not see the ${VERSION_CODENAME}
The ${HOSTNAME} work

Comment: So you want to know how to turn the text strings `buster` or `bullseye` into `Buster` or `Bullseye`? In Bash?

Comment: yes, and how i can get the function get_codename to work, so i now the folder is Buster or Bullseye

Comment: Is this for a school project?

Comment: No, but i are very new and green to this :-(

Comment: The line it was to show what I wanted out

Comment: bash -c '. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME' | sed 's/.*/\u&/'

Comment: how do i get it to know that Buster is a directory to back up ???
so it work with :
VERSION_CODENAME=$(get_codename)

Comment: You need to edit your question to very clearly show what you are trying to do.

Comment: My backup path is : BACKUP_PATH="/RPI-Backup/Buster/${HOSTNAME}/"
I will have the folder Buster to be ${VERSION_CODENAME}
so my backup path will be : BACKUP_PATH="/RPI-Backup/${VERSION_CODENAME}/${HOSTNAME}/"
The ${HOSTNAME} folder work, but i can not get the ${VERSION_CODENAME} folder to work.
The Folder Buster is on my Backup Drive.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: make your backup path match $VERSION_CODENAME

Comment: jsotola >> i try, but i can not get it to work, with i write Buster self in the Backup_path.
i will have the ${VERSION_CODENAME} so it self now the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

get_codename() {
        local VERSION_CODENAME
        VERSION_CODENAME=$(bash -c '. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME' | sed 's/.*/\u&/')
        echo "$VERSION_CODENAME"
}

backupfolder="/RPI-Backup/$(get_codename)/$HOSTNAME/"

echo "backupfolder is:"
echo $backupfolder
```

Comment: @Assassins - Did you know that there is a convention that environment variables ( PAGER , EDITOR , ...) and internal shell variables ( SHELL , BASH_VERSION , ...) are capitalized?. All other variable names should be lower case.

Comment: @Assassins - Also be aware of the difference between `{ }` and `( )` brackets.

Comment: No , I will then remember in the future :-) am happy for your help, and had the patience

Comment: this work to the $HOSTNAME and was no problem

get_hostname() {
    local HOSTNAME
    HOSTNAME=$(hostname -s | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$HOSTNAME"
}

Comment: @Assassins Why do you need the Awk command?

Comment: It not work without this awk, and is print the backup filename

Comment: @Assassins - When you say 'it not work' what way does it not work?

Comment: is will not make the .img file with the server hostname
Hmmm i can not pm you here, so you can see the hole scripts

Comment: @Assassins But this `echo $HOSTNAME` gives me the same as this `echo $(hostname -s)` and also the same as this `echo $(hostname -s) | awk '{print $1}'` Hostname cannot have any spaces, so what does Awk do?

Comment: @Assassins -  Why do you even need a function to get $HOSTNAME?

Comment: The $HOSTNAME is made the folder and the file.img inside the folder.

Comment: @Assassins But $HOSTNAME is the name of an environment variable belonging to the OS

Comment: Yes, but is the only way i could get it to work both ways.

BACKUP_PATH="/RPI-Backup/$(get_codename)/${HOSTNAME}"


dd if=/dev/sda of=${BACKUP_PATH}/${HOSTNAME}${ARCHITECTURE}bits-${BACKUP_DATO}.img bs=1MB

Comment: @Assassins: Please read this from the site's `Help` section: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). In summary: A "`100%`" answer certainly deserves an upvote, and an accept - don't you agree?

Comment: @Seamus -but now I can't delete the damn thing and all these silly comments, which are not what this site is for.

Comment: @Seamus 
Is it forbidden to write further, I have approved his answer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey
Arhhh you mean HOSTNAME=$(hostname -s)
and yes is work :-)

Comment: @Assassins: No - it is not forbidden.

Comment: @Assassins - no, I mean $HOSTNAME already exists before you even write a script.